# WCF Unit Test ReceiveContext

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Is there a way to inject the [ReceiveContext object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.receivecontext.aspx) in order to test a WCF method?

Comment: Instead of testing a WCF method, in general it is better to build the WCF service as extremely thin layer on top of the business layer with just one or two methods. This prevents you from having to test each method. Take a look at [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95) for instance.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, but nevertheless the requirement to inject the ReceiveContext comes from the fact that it is being used as a way to signal that the message has being correctly processed and therefore can be removed from the queue.